# example code for Xorg/X11 record extension fails

Tags: x11, xorg, keylogger

I'm compiling a [basic example](http://blog.csdn.net/findsun/archive/2004/11/19/187878.aspx) (as much as using bare X could be simple...) using the `X11`'s RECORD extension on the latest version of Ubuntu, and I'm getting the following error:

```
RECORD extension for local server is version is 1.13
X Error of failed request:  XRecordBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  135 (RECORD)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (XRecordEnableContext)
  Context in failed request:  0x17
  Serial number of failed request:  10
  Current serial number in output stream:  10
```

Any hints about what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the XRECORD extension is broken in current servers (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/315456, although I hit problems with cnee long after the date the fix was supposed to be available).  You might want to try installing an older Linux distribution in a virtual machine and giving the sample code a try there.

Comment: It worked with a slightly modified code though, and the bug is now marked as fixed.